# VBA Functions (Copy, Paste and Delete) not functioning, what is wrong with the code?

Tags: excel, vba

I am new to Macros and trying to use someone else's work but the option of deleting a row from Data Checking and automatically remove it from Clean Data while also adding it to the Deletions sheet is not working. Here below is the code I'm using
'FIN copying some of the relevant data from the dataset to the 03_TEMPLATE_deletion log.................................................................

```
    'Copying the town cell
    
    Dim town As Range
    Set town = Cells(Application.ActiveCell.Row, CommunityPcode_ColumnNum)
    
    Dim outtown As Range
    Set outtown = CL.Cells(lastrow, 5)
    
    outtown = town
    
    'Copying the column name
    
    Dim colname As Range
    
    Dim outcolname As Range
    Set outcolname = CL.Cells(lastrow, 1)
    
    outcolname = "All"
    
    'Marking that it is deleted
        
    Dim deleteddata As Range
    Set deleteddata = CL.Cells(lastrow, 8)
    
    deleteddata = "Form deleted"
    
    'Insert the reason
    
    Dim ChangeReason As Variant
    ChangeReason = InputBox("Specify the reason for the change:", "Reason", "Clarification from enumerator")
    
    Dim reasonvalue As Range
    Set reasonvalue = CL.Cells(lastrow, 9)
    
    reasonvalue = ChangeReason
    
    'Insert initials
    
    Dim pastinitialsvalue As Range
    Set pastinitialsvalue = CL.Cells(lastrow - 1, 10)
    
    Dim Initials As Variant
    Initials = InputBox("Please provide your initials:", "Initials", pastinitialsvalue)
    
    Dim initialsvalue As Range
    Set initialsvalue = CL.Cells(lastrow, 10)
    
    initialsvalue = Initials
        
    'Delete from Clean Data
    
    Sheets("Clean Data").Select
    Dim DeleteRowClean As Long
    DeleteRowClean = ActiveSheet.Cells.Find(What:=UUID, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole, MatchCase:=True, SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row
    ActiveSheet.Rows(DeleteRowClean).Delete
        
    'Get row value from Raw sheet before deleting from Checking sheet
    Sheets("Raw Data").Select
    Dim DeleteRowRaw As Long
    DeleteRowRaw = ActiveSheet.Cells.Find(What:=UUID, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole, MatchCase:=True, SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row
    
    'Delete from Data Checking

    Sheets("Data Checking").Select
    Dim DeleteRowChecking As Long
    DeleteRowChecking = ActiveSheet.Cells.Find(What:=UUID, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole, MatchCase:=True, SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row
    ActiveSheet.Rows(DeleteRowChecking).Delete

    'Copy from raw data and paste into deletions
    
    Sheets("Raw Data").Select
    Rows(DeleteRowRaw).Select
    Selection.Copy
        
    Sheets("Deletions").Select
    Dim lastrowDel As Long
    lastrowDel = ActiveSheet.Cells.Find("*", SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row + 1
    Rows(lastrowDel).Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    
            
End If
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to avoid using Select in Excel VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba)

Comment: What exactly "isn't working", do you get an error? If so, which row? Is "03_TEMPLATE_deletion log" a sheet because this isn't used in your code..?

Comment: I do not get an error but basically nothing happens - no row deleted in Clean Data, and no row added to Deletions (which are all sheets). Also, no filling out of 03_TEMPLATE_deletion log, which is also a sheet

Comment: Can you post the complete code from `Sub` to `End Sub`